# public_actions permission for score in my game app

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

im using facebook Unity SDK 7.8

i have problem with public_actions permission

```
public void FBlogin()
    {

        List<string> permissions = new List<string> ();
        permissions.Add ("public_profile");
        permissions.Add ("public_actions");

        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (permissions, AuthCallBack);
    }
```

by using these permission when i logged in facebook using app it gives error **invalid scope:public_actions** ..
can any any guide me please ?

waht should i do to access this permission
(NOTE: i have permission in app review email
email
public_profile
publish_actions
user_friends)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method.

[FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions) should be used instead.

From the Facebook Unity SDK:

> *"Prompts the user to authorize your application for publish permissions
>   using the Login Dialog appropriate to the platform."*

Comment: Thanks for you reply can i ask how can i prompt the user to authorize ?

Comment: And when i used loginwithpublishpermission appliaction  crashed

Comment: The authorization dialog will show up on calling that sentence, is handled by the Facebook SDK. On the Unity Editor a mockup dialog is used but in the final build an actual facebook prompt is shown.

The application crashes when you use permission requests other than "publish_actions". Seems like an SDK bug.

So use:
**FB.LogInWithReadPermissions** for _"public_profile"_ and _"user_friends"_
and
**FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions** only for _"publish_actions"_.